# File path for Laravel installed in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel

I have an old legacy project and I am trying to upgrade it to Laravel framework.

So far I have installed the laravel into the `www` directory of my existing project and changing the project one page at a time.

Following is my directory structure.

```
MyProject
├── uploaded_files
├── www
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── images
│   ├── beta (Laravel Project)
```

That is how everything is structured. So my new laravel project url is `myproject.com/beta/public` for now.

Anyway, my concern is that all the existing uploaded files exists in `uploaded_files` directory and some in `www->images` directory.

How can I access those files from `beta (Laravel)` directory so that I can display them and also create new files when necessary.

So far I have tried to access the images directly from the main url but it doesnt work and also tried to create a symlink directly with `uploaded_files` but that doesnt work either.

How can I access the files from `MyProject=> Uploaded files` in `Laravel` controller?

Thank you.